# Running Spring project causes warnings "RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=54571] throws"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I'am running start project from spring initializr I've this warning message

`2021-06-03 15:48:38.987  WARN 9168 --- [MI TCP Accept-0] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=54408] throws`

```
java.io.IOException: The server sockets created using the LocalRMIServerSocketFactory only accept connections from clients running on the host where the RMI remote objects have been exported.
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:114) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:405) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:377) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]

2021-06-03 15:48:39.081  INFO 9168 --- [           main] r.p.mmsclient.MmsclientApplication       : Starting MmsclientApplication using Java 1.8.0_291 on d102 with PID 9168 (C:\Users\NTI\Downloads\mms-client\target\classes started by NTI in C:\Users\NTI\Downloads\mms-client)
2021-06-03 15:48:39.082  INFO 9168 --- [           main] r.p.mmsclient.MmsclientApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-03 15:48:39.314  WARN 9168 --- [MI TCP Accept-0] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=54408] throws

java.io.IOException: The server sockets created using the LocalRMIServerSocketFactory only accept connections from clients running on the host where the RMI remote objects have been exported.
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:114) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:405) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:377) [na:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]

2021-06-03 15:48:39.986  INFO 9168 --- [           main] r.p.mmsclient.MmsclientApplication       : Started MmsclientApplication in 1.556 seconds (JVM running for 2.575)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 10):

I believe that this is related to the local JMX agent and the configuration of the `hosts` file. First, ensure your `hosts` file has an appropriate mapping of `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. Then, add the following VM option:

`-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost`

If you are using IntelliJ, you can find instructions for adding this VM option [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html#configuration-tab).

Comment: Is there a way to just turn off RMI, or is it needed for some reason?